# Bigdesk charts explanation

Tags: elasticsearch

I don't understand what `Search time per second (Δ)` means. Is it the delta of number of milliseconds that the search requests took in previous and current refresh interval? Also there is a Query and Fetch time below the chart, not sure what that represents.

Attached is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Could you explain what kind of tools are you using?

Comment: @pkhlop I am using bigdesk plugin for elastic search to see the average time taken for search queries. I have also created an issue https://github.com/lukas-vlcek/bigdesk/issues/87

Comment: When I do `query_time_in_millis / query_total` for search using node stats api (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_monitoring_individual_nodes.html), I get around 4ms, but the chart `Search time per second (Δ)` lies around 200. I don't know if this is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query in Elasticsearch actually a 2 phased process:

[Query Phase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_query_phase.html) :

During the initial query phase, the query is broadcast to a shard copy (a primary or replica shard) of every shard in the index. Each shard executes the search locally and builds a priority queue of matching documents.

And

[Fetch Phase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_fetch_phase.html) :

The query phase identifies which documents satisfy the search request, but we still need to retrieve the documents themselves. This is the job of the fetch phase.

And that [mail](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/p_4JA_x-K14) explains the `Search time per second (Δ)` part in detail:

> Here is an example for "Search requests per second (Δ)":
>   - You do some "_search" request
>   - It hits 15 shards of some indices on that node, so the value of indices -> search -> "query_total" in nodes stats API [2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_fetch_phase.html) response
>   increases by 15
>   - Bigdesk refresh value is 5000 (5 sec)
>
> As a result the chart should display peak of 3 (15/5) in the Query
>   line. So if the value is ~1500 in your case then it means in average
>   an X number of shards is hit by search requests per second where
>   X=1500*refresh (does it make sense)?
>
> You can see the chart is really only informative (it depends on
>   refresh interval and number of shards). But there is the cumulative
>   "query_total" value displayed as well in the web UI.
>
> Similarly, the second chart "Search time per second (Δ)" displays the
>   average time (in mills) spent in query or fetch phase on the node.
>   Again this value includes all involved shards on that node.

Comment: When I do `query_time_in_millis / query_total` for search using node stats api (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_monitoring_individual_nodes.html), I get around 4ms, but the chart `Search time per second (Δ)` lies around 200. I don't know if this is expected.

Answer (score 2):

[Search time per second (Δ)](https://github.com/lukas-vlcek/bigdesk/blob/4dd7545d4c012bf56def273385a7626cd7d70bc6/js/charts/bigdesk_charts.js#L615) based on 2 series [seies1](https://github.com/lukas-vlcek/bigdesk/blob/4dd7545d4c012bf56def273385a7626cd7d70bc6/js/charts/bigdesk_charts.js#L628) and [serie2](https://github.com/lukas-vlcek/bigdesk/blob/4dd7545d4c012bf56def273385a7626cd7d70bc6/js/charts/bigdesk_charts.js#L637)

they are explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_monitoring_individual_nodes.html)

looks like chart shows these metrics per time unit

Comment: When I do `query_time_in_millis / query_total` for search using node stats api (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_monitoring_individual_nodes.html), I get around 4ms, but the chart `Search time per second (Δ)` lies around 200. I don't know if this is expected.